# Referring to function name within function definition

Tags: recursion, vbscript, rvalue-reference

Given the following:

```
wscript.echo "fx(0)=" & fx(0)

Function fx( v1 )
   fx = 1 + 2
   Wscript.echo "fx=" & fx
End Function
```

Both "echo" lines print the value `3`.  Why doesn't the one inside the function cause a syntax error or recursive loop?  Same question with following sample:

```
wscript.echo "fy()=" & fy()
wscript.echo "fy=" & fy

Function fy
   fy = 1 + 2
   Wscript.echo "fy=" & fy
End Function
```

All echo lines print `3`.

I can't find documentation that describes the behavior when a function definition references it's name as an RVALUE.

TIA.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. I am curious to find out what the answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a VBScript function, the name of the function is a locally scoped variable intended to be equivalent to the return value that comes out of the function. It's no different from any other `Dim var = ...`. To treat it as a function, you need to use call semantics.

Basically, you seem to have gotten used to languages that have first-class functions. VBScript doesn't have them, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Thx for the answer.  I've never read that.  Is that documented or tribal knowledge?

Comment: @mnemotronic I'm not sure. It might not be documented as such. Historically, this has always been how Microsoft's Basics have worked, all the way back to QuickBasic. As the language has grown, additional semantics were added (like `Set`, `Dim As`, and so forth) but the basic way return values are handled has always been the same, instead of a `return ___`, you do `funcname = ___` and if you needed to `return` early you'd do something like `Exit Function`, otherwise that value would be returned at the `End Function`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Plynx, VBScript is somewhat ambigeous. That is why you can use `wscript.echo fy` as well as `wscript.echo fy()` for functions without parameters.

However, this doesn't work the other way around inside functions where you use the functionname as variable. If you do this:

```
Function fy
   fy = 1 + 2
   Wscript.echo "fy=" & fy()
End Function
```

You'll get an `Out of stack space: 'fy'` error. 
Using the functionname as a function can actually be usefull, because you can now use the functionname as a variable or as a function call whilest building recursive functions.

For readability, I'll recommend to use parenthesis in a function call. It will make reviewing or debugging easier for you or your co-worker.